# Which question on MSE has the most failed attempts?

Tags: discussion, answers, statistics, deleted-answers

Half an hour ago, someone posted another answer to the question [How does one prove the matrix inequality $\det\left(6(A^3+B^3+C^3)+I_n\right)\ge5^n\det(A^2+B^2+C^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/860294) If this answer turns out to be wrong, it would be the **fourteenth** failed attempt for that question (there were nominally 15 answers at the time of writing, but one of them is actually a comment), otherwise the number is 13. This makes me wonder which question on MSE (soft questions excluded) has attracted the longest list of wrong answers.

Comment: Browsing through [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) gives a good idea. I don't know if a more systematic approach exists, since AFAIK deleted posts don't show up in SEDE.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you know there were 14 or 15 attempts? [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/860294/timeline) didn't give me anything. [This](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/485399/deleted-questions) shows a list of deleted _questions_...

Comment: Maybe [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/361518) could be relevant.

Comment: @Watson Users with more than 10k reputation can see deleted answers, so I assume user1551 just counted them.

Comment: It does look like this is the fourteenth wrong answer.

Comment: On MathOverflow, this question has had 17 answers, 16 of them deleted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q

Comment: Take into account that a deleted answer is not necessarily a wrong answer. In most cases the converse of this will be true.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this page](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/361518/non-deleted-questions-with-most-deleted-answers), here are some of the questions with the greatest number of deleted answers, and with only $0$ or $1$ answer:

[image]

Apparently, [How does one prove the matrix inequality $\det\left(6(A^3+B^3+C^3)+I_{n}\right)\ge 5^n\det(A^2+B^2+C^2)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860294) is the winner, and [Does there exist a bijection of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with itself such that the forward map is connected but the inverse is not?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952466) is the second one, with 10 failed attempts.

If you also wanted to consider "solved" (?) questions, then [Evaluate $ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac1{(1+x^2)(1+\tan x)}\:\mathrm dx\;$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452) has 27 deleted answers. We could also consider [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-ldots-1), with 28 deleted answers, but maybe you consider it as a "soft" question...

Comment: What about the one at the bottom with 27 deleted answers?

Comment: If you count questions with $≥2$ answers, then this one with 27 deleted answers has the most failed attempts. However it has now a highly upvoted answer, this is why I didn't take it into account.

Comment: According to your list, technically the one with 28 deleted answers ([Is $0.999999999\ldots = 1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11)) wins, but I think the 27 deleted answers in the integral question are more serious attempts, so I would vote for the integral question.

Comment: @user1551 : ok, that's fine for me too!

Comment: How do you know the deletions weren't just duplicate answers or a flood of spambots?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck: I can't see the deleted answers, sorry.

Comment: Related: https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/533886/non-deleted-questions-with-most-deleted-answers